# How to read a big clob data from a file?

Tags: java, file-io, clob

I need to read a file line by line.
The data in the file can be anything, a small string or a huge Clob/Blob/XML.
But I am facing a problem, I am using `String row = dataInputStream.readLine()` to get the data, line by line. But if it is a big Clob/Blob/XML data, this method is throwing error, because it is not able to fit the huge data into the String. What should I do?

Comment: If the data can be anything it makes no sense to read it line by line.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using a reader. If this is a binary (unknown) file, you should read it as bytes from something like a `BufferedInputStream`. Then do whatever processing you need with the data. Apache commons-io has a nice IOUtils class to easily read bytes from a stream into a byte array, see http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, by anything I meant any kind of data. The file I need to read is an exported table from database (in delimited format). So it will be in simple text format. But the length of each row may be very huge if the table had any CLOB/BLOB column. How do I read such a big row from the file? Reading character by character is an option, but I wanted to find a more efficient way doing it.

Comment: Mixed-type data needs to be treated as such. The most robust way to handle this is to read the file as bytes, split each field with the delimiter and process them individually.